# React-Select is not showing selected options on the searchbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

When I try and select an option from the dropdown it doesn't show on the searchbar if I add an if statement inside the onChange handler function, when I remove "if statement" the selected options get displayed on the bar.

```
                <Select
                  isMulti
                  name="colors"
                  options={cat.subs.map((sub) => {
                    return { value: sub, label: sub.name };
                  })}
                  className="basic-multi-select"
                  classNamePrefix="select"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
```

And this is the change handler function, it works perfectly, but the selected option are not displayed on the searchbar

```
const handleChange = (newValue, actionMeta) => {
  if (actionMeta.action === "remove-value") {
    removeSubCategory(actionMeta.removedValue.value);
  } else if (actionMeta.action === "select-option") {
    addSubCategory(actionMeta.option.value);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `removeSubCategory` function removes the value from your data, it won't be available to select again, will it? Please can you provide more context on how those functions modify the data that provides your options.

Comment: the options shown in the dropdown menu are not affected they are on a seperate array, I still can use the removeSubCategory functions because I can't remove any options because they are not displayed at the bar